# How to install web browser and browsing website in linx vps/dedicated server

Tags: linux, centos, browser, vps

I have a centos vps server. I want to install web browser on my server and browsing website from installed web browser. Is it possible. If possible please, help me sharing your idea. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possibilities for doing this:

1. Install a full graphical environment and then

   a. Use X-Forwarding and run a browser on the remote server.

   b. Use remote desktop/VNC to connect remotely to the server.
2. Install a proxy server and proxy your web browsing through it.
3. Install a VPN server and connect your computer to the VPN.

In the last two options, you would be running your browser on your local computer, but your network traffic will go out through the server, so you will appear to be coming from the server's IP address.